# Initialize Automapper + TDD + MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tdd, automapper

I'm creating one test to action edit. That's action return one viewmodel was that create from entity using automapper, but in my test I receve exception because automapper not was initialized. How do I do initialize automapper in my tests?

My test code below:

```
    public void Action_Editar_Deve_Retornar_ProdutoFormModel_Carregado()
    {
        var produto = FakeDadosProduto.CriarProduto(1);
        var produtos = new Mock<IProdutos>();
        produtos
            .Setup(p => p.Obter(It.IsAny<Guid>()))
            .Returns(produto);

        var controller = CriarController(produtos.Object);

        var viewResult = controller.Editar(Guid.NewGuid());

        Assert.AreEqual("produto teste-1", ((ProdutoFormModel)viewResult.Model).Nome);
    }
```

Tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test setup (or test fixture setup to call the initialization just once) you can call the method that initialize Automapper. Suppose you have a method **InitializeAutoMapper** in your **global.asax**, your test fixture setup should be:

```
[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    //MvcApplication is your global.asax class
    MvcApplication.InitializeAutoMapper(); 
}
```

Also, you can inject the mapping engine of Automapper in your controllers and fake it in your tests and so you dont need initialize Automapper.

```
public MyController(IMappingEngine mappingEngine){...}
```

Comment: I'm not gonna inject automapper in controller, because I created a viewresult to do this.